# Unity - Build is different from Run

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a platformer where the color of a zone changes when a player enters it. This works fine for my test runs, but on my build, the color of the next zone over changes.

Specifically, my zones are all Sprites in the Hierarchy, each with unique Tags of "Success" + the number of the zone. When I run on my build, the collision detector detects the zone number as 1 more than it should be.

**Build**

[image]

**Run**

[image]

My collision script:

```
public class CollisionDetector2 : NetworkBehaviour {
   void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
   {
      if (!isLocalPlayer)
         return;
      Debug.Log(other.tag);
      if (other.tag.Substring(0, 7) == "Success")
      {
         if (isServer)
        {
            GameObject.Find("GameController").GetComponent<ProgressTracker>    ().Collide(Int32.Parse(other.tag.Substring(7)));
         }
        else
        {
            CmdNotifyCollide(Int32.Parse(other.tag.Substring(7)));
         }
      }
   }

   void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
   {

      if (!isLocalPlayer)
         return;
      if (other.tag.Substring(0, 7) == "Success")
     {
        if (isServer)
         {
            GameObject.Find("GameController").GetComponent<ProgressTracker>().Exit(Int32.Parse(other.tag.Substring(7)));
        }
         else
        {
           CmdNotifyExit(Int32.Parse(other.tag.Substring(7)));
        }
      }
  }

   [Command]
  void CmdNotifyCollide(int num)
   {
      GameObject.Find("GameController").GetComponent<ProgressTracker>().Collide(num);
   }

   [Command]
  void CmdNotifyExit(int num)
   {
     GameObject.Find("GameController").GetComponent<ProgressTracker>().Exit(num);
   }
}
```

My sprite color change script:

```
public class ProgressTracker : NetworkBehaviour {

   public SyncListBool success = new SyncListBool();

   void Start()
  {
      success.Clear();
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     {
        success.Add(false);
      }

      success.Callback = OnSuccessChange;
   }

   public void Collide(int num)
   {
     if (!isServer)
         return;

      //Debug.Log(num);
      success[num - 1] = true;

   }

   public void Exit(int num)
   {
     if (!isServer)
        return;

      success[num - 1] = false;
   }

   public void OnSuccessChange(SyncListBool.Operation op, int index)
   {
     int total = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     {
        if (success == true)
        {
            total += 1;
         }
     }

     if (total == 2)
     {
        NetworkManager.singleton.ServerChangeScene("SeniorProject3");
      }

     if (success[index])
      {
           SpriteRenderer block = GameObject.Find("Success" + (index + 1)).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
           block.color = new Color32(104, 104, 104, 255);
      }
      else
     {

            SpriteRenderer block = GameObject.Find("Success" + (index + 1)).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
           block.color = new Color32(182, 182, 182, 255);

     }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid use of **Find** and **GetComponent**, they are time-consuming methods and can make bad effects on physics simulation.

To improve collision detect change the **interpolation mode** on the **rigidbody**.